# How to get text of link in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My objective is to display the text or inner html of a link *after* the link itself essentially creating a duplicate.

At this point, when hovering over a link, I can display the text `TEST` after the link with:

```
.link
{
   color:aqua;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: none;
}
.link:hover span {display:none;
.link:hover:after {content:"TEST";}
```

[image]

However, I would like the text to be "CoDe".  How would one display the actual text of the link itself after the link with jQuery?

I have tried simply to log the content of the hovered link to console, but this does not work:

```
$('#link').hover(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the the text of the link and change the content of `link:hover:after` with jQuery ?

Comment: Is the link static, or is it dynamically added after page load?

Comment: I don't think jQuery can modify pseudo-elements like `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: I'm upvoting this as an example of a well-asked question. Although I don't really see a use of doing this, it is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: the link is dynamically added